# UIComponent documentation — fail

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

It's been about 2 years since I built a component extending the `fl.core.UIComponent` class, so I figured I would refresh my memory a bit and review the docs. But the docs are not listing all the methods. I know that there are more functions then what is listed on the help page.

If you go to the adobe help for [UIComponent](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/core/UIComponent.html) page and scroll down to the protected methods I only see the `getStyleVaue()` method when I know there are more like the "draw" method is one for example.

How can adobe document a class and leave out one of the most important methods.
Is there a filter or something I am missing?

**Note:** This is `fl.core.UIComponent`, not the flex one.

Comment: hmm not sure why you are seeing that, i just checked and can see lots of methods as expected

Comment: @Neil Oh I see a lot of methods just not under the protected method area

Comment: ah ok you did mention that in your post, usually they don't list protected methods.

Comment: @Neil Odd I never noticed it before this. If its not listed then how would I know what can be over-ridden then?

Comment: Look at the code! It's open source. It's the best way! :)

Comment: If you are extending the class your IDE usually tells you what can be overridden with intellisense, flash builder does anyway.

Comment: @Neil True but what I was trying to do was to brush up the UIComponent framework itself by going through the docs and examining each method and how they all come together. Can't do that if a method is not listed. Anyway you might as well put that as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: @The_asMan I don't think fl.core.UIComponent is open source, as it comes with Flash CS, I know you can see the .as file in the Common\Configuration\Component Source\ActionScript 3.0\User Interface\fl\core, finally maybe best to close this question as its not really an SO programming question, don't you agree?

Answer (score 0):

You have encountered the wonderful game invented by Adobe called "guess the filter." Make sure you have Flash selected, and the appropriate version of the product.

[image]

Comment: I wish it was that simple. If you can find a filter setting that allows "protected function draw()" to show please tell me how.